# what is SCHEMA_MIGIMP..MIGRATION_STATUS?

Tags: mysql

There is a line in my script as

```
DELETE FROM &SCHEMA_MIGIMP..MIGRATION_STATUS WHERE MIG_JOBID = 213;
```

what is the meaning of `&SCHEMA_MIGIMP..MIGRATION_STATUS` ?

Comment: Posting the relevant part of your code would be helpful...&SCHEMA_MIGIMP seems to be related to your code

Comment: i doubt you are using MySQL, `&` is not valid to be used as a identifier (database, names and or columns names) only when using backticks, which you are cleary are not using atleast not in question?